# Surveillance through Arduino and Web

Tags: php, html, arduino, live-streaming

I wanted to ask if it is possible to send the video feed from a camera to an Arduino board, and through the ethernet sheild send it to an Apache web server, and then displaying it on the browser in some form.  I am not trying to transmit the audio and video together, just the video. Audio is not my concern at all..
I have seen people sending JPEG images across the web but never a video. I am new to both the web and arduino, so i don't even know if it is simple enough to send live streams through a web server even without using the Arduino and using a PC instead. If it is possible, i would be much obliged if a link is provided to the possible php/html functions that might be used for this task, as these are the only web languages that i use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible since all Arduino boards have very weak processing power to handle video streaming.
Also, data cant be transfered through the serial link fast enough and there is not enough SRAM space to buffer the frames.

Personally, i recommend trying Raspberry PI + Motion for live streaming video.
If you want to stick with Arduino, the upcoming Tre board i think will be able to do such a job, but it will be way more expensive than the PI solution.

Check these links:

[Raspberry PI webcam server tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NVrqNaLxU_g)

[Raspberry Pi remote webcam](http://www.instructables.com/id/Raspberry-Pi-remote-webcam/)

Comment: Thank you. I am looking in to this stuff, i think i might use this strategy. But the problem is that using these techniques and the ones described in similar tutorials is that you could only access the camera feed in the local network. My project is based on the Web, so i was hoping to send the video feed to be processed and displayed by the web server. So i could access it without the need of a static IP address.

Comment: I think you can access the stream outside your local network if you provide public ip or domain to the settings of motion and proper port forwarding. Dynamic ip problem can be easily solved using a ddns service such as no ip. I use it and it works perfect! I had tested streaming to the internet in the past with motion and it worked only at mozilla though. Accept the answer if it helped you, thanks!

Comment: Thanks mate. I have some other stuff going on, it will take me some time to try these out. But thanks for your help.